# How to filter MySQL results to display LIMIT 1 on per user basis?

Tags: mysql, sql, filter, greatest-n-per-group

Here is a screenshot of the SQL command results:

[image]

Here is the SQL command:

```
SELECT inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id AS cbsubsUserID, inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.id AS cbsubsId, inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.status AS status, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id     AS paymentSubID, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.stop_date AS paymentStopDate, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.id AS paymentID
FROM inl_cbsubs_subscriptions
INNER JOIN inl_cbsubs_payment_items
ON inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.id=inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id
WHERE status='C'
ORDER BY paymentID DESC;
```

I am looking to adjust this command so that I have only the most recent result showing on a per user basis.  So in other words, this is what the table should resemble in this case:

[image]

As you can see, the `cbsubsUserID` only shows one result per ID whereas before there were multiple results for the `596` id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the most recent result, the best way to do it is with `not exists`:

```
SELECT s.user_id AS cbsubsUserID, s.id AS cbsubsId, s.status AS status,
       i.subscription_id AS paymentSubID, i.stop_date AS paymentStopDate, i.id AS paymentID
FROM inl_cbsubs_subscriptions s INNER JOIN
     inl_cbsubs_payment_items i
     ON s.id = i.subscription_id
WHERE s.status = 'C' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from inl_cbsubs_payment_items i2
                  where i2.subscription_id = i.subscription_id and
                    i2.id > i.id
                 )
ORDER BY paymentID DESC;
```

You will want an index on `inl_cbsubs_payment_items(subscription_id, paymentid)`.

What this is saying is:  "Get me all the items for a given subscription id that have no bigger payment stop dates for that subscription".  It is a fancy way of saying "get me the most recent for each subscription id", but it tends to work best in the database.

Comment: I have attempted this solution and get `#1054 - Unknown column 'i2.payment_stop_date' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Thanks for the update.  This is properly filtering 1 result per user.  The only problem is that it pulls the max value from the `paymentStopDate` column.  I need to pull the max from `paymentID` and preserve `paymentStopDate` associated with that entry.

Comment: I just tried and got `#1054 - Unknown column 'i2.paymentid' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @Presto . . . I don't know what the columns in your tables are called.  You said `paymentID` in your comment.  Is it `paymentSubId`?  Try that instead.

Comment: THank you for the patience, I am a novice at best with SQL.  The full name prior to aliases is `inl_cbsubs_payment_items.id` it looks like this is what you are calling `i.id`.  Does that help explain it?

Comment: @Presto . . . I guess so.  The `i` is just a convenient abbreviation (called a table alias).  I am always surprised when I see an `id` column in a table and the `id` can have duplicates -- seems like a bad design to me.  That aside, you want the `>` comparison to be on the field that you want the "max" of.

Comment: I finally figured it out.  I just had to change `i2.paymentid > i.paymentid` to `i2.id > i.id` in the `where` clause.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [**`GROUP BY`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to achieve this

```
SELECT inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id AS cbsubsUserID, inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.id AS cbsubsId, inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.status AS status, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id     AS paymentSubID, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.stop_date AS paymentStopDate, inl_cbsubs_payment_items.id AS paymentID
FROM inl_cbsubs_subscriptions
INNER JOIN inl_cbsubs_payment_items
ON inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.id=inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id
WHERE status='C'
GROUP BY inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id
ORDER BY paymentID DESC;
```

Comment: Can you adjust this to show the entry on the greatest value for `paymentID`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id AS cbsubsUserID, MAX(inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.id) AS cbsubsId, inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.status AS status, MAX(inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id)     AS paymentSubID, x.stop_date AS paymentStopDate, x.blah AS paymentID
FROM inl_cbsubs_subscriptions
INNER JOIN inl_cbsubs_payment_items
ON inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.id=inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT inl_cbsubs_payment_items.stop_date as stop_date ,
 MAX(inl_cbsubs_payment_items.id) as blah
 FROM inl_cbsubs_subscriptions
 INNER JOIN inl_cbsubs_payment_items
 ON inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.id=inl_cbsubs_payment_items.subscription_id
 WHERE status='C'
 GROUP BY inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id)as x
ON x.stop_date=inl_cbsubs_payment_items.stop_date AND x.blah=inl_cbsubs_payment_items.id
WHERE status='C'
GROUP BY inl_cbsubs_subscriptions.user_id
ORDER BY paymentID DESC;
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me right out of the box.  Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: After working with this for a while I have found that this is disassociating the stop date with the particular entry.  In other words it show the max value, but the stop date is not the same date associated with that entry.  Any suggestions on how to adjust?

Comment: @Presto Yes ,it can be done but the question is which row?What is the criteria for a specific row in that group?

Comment: `paymentID` is the column that determines the most recent record.

Comment: Perhaps max date and max paymentid are not exactly synchronized?

Comment: that is correct. there are times when the stop date may be greater on other entries.  I just need to know the max paymentid and then pull the stop date that is associated with it.

Comment: thank you for the update.  I have attempted this change yet unfortunately the results are not as expected.  I apologize that this is being more difficult than I initially imagined, but ultimately I need it to show one record per user and the record should be the greatest value available for that user.  Lastly the record should stay intact.

Answer (score 0):

To get the most recent record per group you can do so

```
SELECT DISTINCT
s.user_id AS cbsubsUserID, 
s.id AS cbsubsId, 
s.status AS `status`, 
si.subscription_id     AS paymentSubID,
si.stop_date AS paymentStopDate, 
si.id AS paymentID
FROM inl_cbsubs_subscriptions s
INNER JOIN inl_cbsubs_payment_items si
ON s.id=si.subscription_id
 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(stop_date) stop_date ,subscription_id ,MAX(id) id
FROM inl_cbsubs_payment_items 
GROUP BY subscription_id ) max_si
ON 
(max_si.subscription_id=si.subscription_id 
AND max_si.id =si.id 
AND  max_si.stop_date = si.stop_date )
WHERE `status`='C'
ORDER BY paymentID DESC;
```

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid this is giving the following error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(stop_date) stop_date ,subscription_id ,MAX(id) id FROM inl_cbsubs_pay' at line 11`

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid I have tried the update and now get `#1054 - Unknown column 'si.max_si' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it will load but it is not filtering the way I have described.